# Adjoint of Generalized Eigenvalue Problem

Tags: linear-algebra

I have seen that for a given matrix A, its adjoint A* is defined as the conjugate transpose of A and has eigenvalues that are conjugates of the eigenvalues for A. I was wondering if there is a similar relationship in the generalized eigenvalue problem case 
\begin{equation} (A-\lambda B)v=0 \end{equation}
How would I go about finding the adjoint for this case? Is there something similar to taking the conjugate transpose of A and B to get the adjoint of the system? Are the eigenvalues still conjugates of the original system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\lambda\in \mathbb C$ be an eigenvalue. That is, $A-\lambda B$ is not injective. This implies that $(A-\lambda B)^*=A^*-\bar\lambda B^*$ is not surjective.

In case the vector space is finite-dimensional, then this implies that $A^*-\bar\lambda B^*$ is not injective.

Hence, $\bar\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of the adjoint generalized eigenvalue problem
$$
(A^*-\mu B^*)w=0.
$$